# Get Minimum Values at Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql

I am working with a loan dataset, and I have the following code that finds the first 30, 60, and 90 day delinquencies (`dpdXX_mob`) for a given trade key. The script works as intended, but I was wondering if there was a more effective approach to getting these values.

```
SELECT 
    90dpd.trade_key AS trade_key,
    90dpd.first_dpd90_mob,
    60dpd.first_dpd60_mob,
    30dpd.first_dpd30_mob
FROM (
        SELECT trade_key, min(mob) AS first_dpd90_mob
        FROM base_table
        WHERE 90_day_counter = 1
    ) AS 90dpd
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT trade_key, min(mob) AS first_dpd60_mob
            FROM base_table
            WHERE 60_day_counter = 1
        ) AS 60dpd
          ON 90dpd.trade_key = 60dpd.trade_key
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT trade_key, min(mob) AS first_dpd30_mob
            FROM base_table
            WHERE 30_day_counter = 1
        ) AS 30dpd
          ON 90dpd.trade_key = 30dpd.trade_key
```

Comment: Just use a `group by trade_key` and `case` expressions to pull out the individual `mob` values you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select trade_key,  
       min(case when 90_day_counter = 1 then mob end) first_dpd90_mob,
       min(case when 60_day_counter = 1 then mob end) first_dpd60_mob,
       min(case when 30_day_counter = 1 then mob end) first_dpd30_mob
from base_table
group by trade_key
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!